# Sending message with iframe contents through google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to have a chrome extension interact with a page invisibly. To do this, I'm loading that page in an iframe in the chrome extension's background page. However, I want to both a) be able to read the contents of that iframe and b) interact with the contents of that iframe.

Currently, I'm loading that background page and it's associated javascript files, and have separately a content script which should load when the iframe loads. Specifically:

content-script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log(document);
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    data: document
  });
});
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
  console.log(message.data);
});
```

background.html:

```
<script src=bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js></script>
<script src=background.js></script>
<iframe src="https://messenger.com" id="iframe"/>
```

The expected behavior in the console would be a console.log displaying the document (from the content-script line 2), followed by a console log displaying the document (as passed from the content script to background.js). However, the second console.log instead prints an empty object. Any ideas why this might be and/or how to fix this?

Comment: You can't send `document` or any DOM element in a message. Only JSON-serializable objects/types [may be passed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to pass the contents of the DOM element? As in, retrieve all text from the DOM, and pass that in the message instead?

Comment: Yes, see [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) documentation for more details.

Comment: I've actually already tested this with JSON.stringify(document); it printed successfully inside the content script but not inside the background.js file. Am I missing something super basic here?

Comment: Yes you do, as I said DOM elements, including `document`, are not JSON-serializable, here's the result of `JSON.stringify(document)` for stackoverflow: `{"jQuery17103365562485996634":2}`

Comment: Thanks mate, this was super helpful. Ended up jquerying the specific elements I needed, working like a charm.